# Find the limit or prove that it does not exist $\lim_{(x, \space y) \to (0, \space 0)} f(x, y) $ where $f(x, y) = \frac{x^5-y^5}{x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Find the limit or prove that it does not exist
$$\lim_{(x, \space y) \to (0, \space 0)}  f(x, y) $$ where $$f(x, y) = \frac{x^5-y^5}{x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4}$$

---

Iterated limit $\displaystyle{\lim_{y \to 0}} \space \displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0}} \space f(x, y) = \displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0}} \space \displaystyle{\lim_{y \to 0}} \space f(x, y) = 0$, but it doesn't mean that $\displaystyle{\lim_{(x, \space y) \to (0, \space 0)}}  f(x, y) = 0 $.

I've also tried substitution $x = r \cdot \cos \phi, \space y = r \cdot \sin \phi$, which gave me $ \frac{r(\cos^5\phi - \sin^5\phi)}{(\cos^2\phi-\sin^2\phi)^2} $. If $x \to 0$ and $y \to 0$, then $r \to 0$. So, $\displaystyle{\lim_{r \to 0}} \space \frac{r(\cos^5\phi - \sin^5\phi)}{(\cos^2\phi-\sin^2\phi)^2} = 0$.

But I have a feeling that original limit doesn't exist and WolframAlpha says that too and I'm stuck here. If my assumption is correct, how to prove it properly?

Comment: Check the plot of the function to get an idea of curves y(x) along which the limit should be different, and then compute said limit along those two curves.For instance, if you choose $\phi=\pi/4$, you get 0/0, so the limit may not be $0$.

Comment: This function is *not* defined in any neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ (minus the origin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit doesn't exist. If $n\in\mathbb N$, then$$f\left(\sqrt{\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n^4}},\frac1n\right)=\left(\left(\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n^4}\right)^{5/2}-\frac1{n^5}\right)n^8$$and$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{n^4}\right)^{5/2}-\frac1{n^5}\right)n^8=\infty.$$

Answer (score 2):

I think your substitution gives you a hint. The angles $\tan\phi =\pm 1$ are the problematic ones, i.e., the limit along the lines $\pm x=y$. You can check that along these lines there's a divergence.

Answer (score 0):

In the posting, $$ f(r,\phi)=\frac{r(\cos^5\phi -\sin^5\phi
)}{(\cos^2\phi -\sin^2\phi)^2} = \underbrace{\frac{r}{\cos\
\phi-\sin\ \phi}}_{=g}\underbrace{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^4\
\sin^i\phi\cos^{4-i}\phi }{(\cos\ \phi+\sin\ \phi)^2} }_{=h}$$

When $f(r,0)=r$, so $\lim_r\ f=0$.

Further, $\lim_{\phi \rightarrow
\pi/4}\ h $ exists. We have a sequence $\phi_n<\pi/4,\
\phi_n\rightarrow \pi/4$ s.t. $ \cos\ \phi_n > \sin\ \phi_n$. We let
$$r_n =\sqrt{\cos\ \phi_n - \sin\ \phi_n}.$$ Hence $$ g(r_n,\phi_n) =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{ \cos\ \phi_n - \sin\ \phi_n }}\rightarrow \infty$$
so that $f(r_n,\phi_n)$ goes to $\infty$.